# Why does fading in a webview using an alpha value not animate linearly? (goes from alpha 0 to 1 instantly)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-animation

I am trying to fade in a `RelativeLayout` that contains a `WebView` after the page has finished loading. It mostly works, except I cannot get it to fade in. The animation's duration is correct, but the opacity stays 0 until the very end of the animation, when it instantly becomes 1, so there's no fade-in effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                relativeLayout.setAlpha(0f);
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                relativeLayout.animate()
                        .alpha(1f)
                        .setDuration(shortAnimationDuration);
            }
        });
```

My XML

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/webview"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have noticed the same thing. I think the problem is because there is some UI blocking going on during the time the initial page is loading. This problem appears for both fading in or fading out. One possible workaround is to overlay the webview with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and fade that in instead. This won't remove the duration it takes to load the webview but if the animation is long enough, it may make it look like the webview is being animated into view. After the page loads, remove the overlay.